# Image not showing up on heroku, but works on local

Tags: heroku

I have a little image that is showing up as a dead link on heroku, but not on my local, the image files were git pushed with everything else. Whats more is I have other images that show up just fine.

the view file for broken image

```
        <% if report.status == 4 or report.status == 5 %>
            <img src="<%= image_path('greenlight.png') %>" id="status">
        <% elsif report.status == 2 or report.status == 3 %>
            <img src="<%= image_path('yellowlight.png') %>" id="status">
        <% elsif report.status == 1 %>
            <img src="<%= image_path('redlight.png') %>" id="status">
        <% end %>
```

view file for working image

```
    <div id="header"><header>
        <img src="<%= image_path('whfd_logo.png') %>" id="whfd">
        <img src="<%= image_path('iaff.png') %>" id="iaff">
        <span>text removed<br />
        text removed</span>
    </header></div>
```

view source fro broken image

```
        <img src="/images/yellowlight.png" id="status">
```

view source for working image

```
        <img src="/images/whfd_logo.png?1329844130" id="whfd">
        <img src="/images/iaff.png?1329844130" id="iaff">
```

when the image works on my local the view source looks like this

```
    <img src="/images/yellowlight.png?1329096113" id="status">
```

whats going on here? why is the number string after the image missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future you could run `git add -A` that will add AND delete any files you...well, added or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. I need to learn more about git.

running `git add .` before my git commit fixed it.